# JavaScript inside user control doesn't run

Tags: javascript, asp.net, user-controls

I'm having troubles with user controls and JavaScript.

I have a user control that has a timer in it. The timer is being updated every 5 seconds by JavaScript inside the user control itself (in the .ascx file). During run time, a few instances of my user control is instantiated within the same page, inside an UpdatePanel.

The timer works just fine when there is only one instance of my user control. But when there are more than one instance, only the timer of the last instance gets updated every 5 seconds, and the rest don't.

Here's my script:

```
var start = new Date('<%=session.startTime%>');
var stat = '<%=session.status%>'

UpdateValues();
AutoUpdateValues();

function AutoUpdateValues(){
    setInterval(function () {
        UpdateValues();
    }, 5000);
}

function UpdateValues() {
    //update time elapsed
    var totalSec = Math.ceil((new Date() - start) / 1000); //time elapsed in seconds
    var hr = Math.floor(totalSec/3600);
    var min = Math.floor((totalSec % 3600)/60);
    var sec = totalSec % 60;
    if (stat == 2) {
        $('#<%=lblTimeElapsed.ClientID%>').text(hr + "h " + min + "m " + sec + "s" );
    }
}
```

---

[Update]

```
var amnt = $('#<%=lblAmount.ClientID%>');
var start = new Date('<%=session.startTime%>');
var stat = '<%=session.status%>';

<%=this.ClientID %>UpdateValues();
<%=this.ClientID %>AutoUpdateValues();

function <%=this.ClientID %>AutoUpdateValues() {
    setInterval(<%=this.ClientID %>UpdateValues, 5000);
}

function <%=this.ClientID %>UpdateValues() {
    //update time elapsed
    var totalSec = Math.ceil((new Date() - start) / 1000); //time elapsed in seconds
    var hr = Math.floor(totalSec / 3600);
    var min = Math.floor((totalSec % 3600) / 60);
    var sec = totalSec % 60;
    if (stat == 2) {
        $('[id^="<%=this.ClientID %>lblTimeElapsed"]').text(hr + "h " + min + "m " + sec + "s");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The setInterval function creates a new object each time it starts. If you're using multiple instances, you should create an array of the setInterval constructors.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. But can you elaborate some more? Which objects are being recreated in my code particularly and how do I create an array of the setInterval constructors? It would be very much appreciated if you could give me a simple example of that. Thanks for your time

Comment: Oh, it's a different problem I think. UpdateValues() doesn't need to be called from the anonymous function; it can be called directly by setInterval.

Comment: `function AutoUpdateValues(){
    setInterval(UpdateValues(), 5000);
}`

Comment: I still get the same result with this :(

Answer (score 1):

Each time you add the same control asp.net repeat it in with the same page, this lead to repeat the script section in your page with the same code and function names

since ASP.NET renaming the controls, you need to depend on <%=this.ClientID=>

and just update all the controls that has the value

```
 $('[id*="lblTimeElapsed"]').text("set value");
```

my solution is to add prefix on your function name like this

```
function <%=this.ClientID %>AutoUpdateValues(){
    setInterval(function () {
        <%=this.ClientID %>UpdateValues();
    }, 5000);
}
function <%=this.ClientID %>UpdateValues(){// your logic }
```

instated of

```
$('#<%=lblTimeElapsed.ClientID%>').text("set value");
```

use this

```
$('[id^="<%=this.ClientID %>lblTimeElapsed"]').text("set value");
```

so when you call method will be something like this

```
<%=this.ClientID %>UpdateValues();
<%=this.ClientID %>AutoUpdateValues();
```

anther solution can raise here to solve a problem of invoke one method to a set of controls in the same time with out run many functions is to use singleton object as follow.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your suggestion. I tried it but didn't get it to work. Did I miss something? Please check my update. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think I am miss to add _
`$('[id^="<%=this.ClientID %>_lblTimeElapsed"]')`
open your page on chrome browser and right click -> inspect element on your control and view the id attribute for your label, try this for at least tow controls and then see how asp.net named your id

Comment: This is the id that was produced `ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl01_lblTimeElapsed`. It now matches the id of the actual control. But I still get the same result. Only the last instance is updated. Do I need to add _ to the function names too?

Comment: View HTML source and search in for function names, I think you need to make this code around `$(function () {   replace your code here     } )`

Comment: $('[id$="_lblTimeElapsed"]')